# In visual studio debugger, is there a way to see the CPU utilization of GC threads?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, garbage-collection

I am working on some multithreaded code and I am pretty sure that my parallelism is hurt by how much the GC has to run.  (It appears to be doing ~100 1Gen collections per second).   I would like to tease out the different between data contention and the GC itself by looking at the CPU utilization of the GC.   I know that I can do this perfmon, but I would really like it if Visual Studio could show me this.  Is it possible?

Comment: Did you check if any profiling options (assuming VS 2017 community) provide info you are after?

Comment: If you have VS 2017 (15.8) or VS 2019 there is a .NET Object Allocation Tracking Too to the profiling tools (Alt +F2) that tracks both allocations (along with stacks at allocation) and objects collected during a GC. If you try it out it would be great to hear your feedback (I work on the tool).

Comment: To make such profiling, your choice should be PerfView. You have there in GCStats report true and meaningful GC overhead stats.